# JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures: iOs9 error for Ionic / AngularFire app

Tags: ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase, ios9

I updated my Xcode today and run my Ionic app on iOs9 build. New error pop up on Xcode console each time I click from a ng-repeat list to a detail view. Error is:

```
error JSON.stringify()ing argument: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.
```

The error seem to be caused by AngularFire firebaseObject. Here is how to duplicated the problem (has to build to ios and see the error in xcode7):

1. Use Ionic starter sidemenu template by running:

   ```
   $ sudo npm install -g ionic cordova
   $ ionic start myApp sidemenu
   ```
2. modify the PlaylistsCtrl and PlaylistCtrl as below:

```js
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {
  $scope.playlists = [];
  var ref = new Firebase(MYFIREBASEURL);
  var tasks = $firebaseArray(ref.child('tasks'));
  $scope.playlists = tasks;
})

.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseObject) {
  var id = $stateParams.playlistId;
  console.log(id);
  var ref = new Firebase(MYFIREBASEURL);
  var task = $firebaseObject(ref.child('tasks').child(id));
  console.log(task);
  $scope.task = task;
});
```

Modify the 2 views: Playlists and Playlist  that come with the starter template as below:

```html
<ion-view view-title="Playlists">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.$id}}">
        {{playlist.$id}} / {{playlist.title}}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-text-wrap">{{task.title}} / {{task.$id}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>

<ion-view view-title="Playlist">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>{{task.$id}}</h1>
    <p>{{task.title}}</p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Build the sidemenu starter app by running $ionic build ios and then open the xcode file in xcode7. Run on ACTUAL DEVICE - like an iPhone 5S (my device). Take note in the xcode log window.

When click the list item and go to the detail playlist view, it throw error like this

> 2015-09-29 10:20:03.868 firebaseObjerr[572:142668] error JSON.stringify()ing argument: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.

And adding the ios9 fix indicated here: [enter link description here](http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/)
did not solve the problem. 
Please help!

**[EDIT]**

Here is my system info (As Ionic, Cordova are latest):

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:  
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.8
ios-deploy version: 1.7.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.1 
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v0.12.5
Xcode version: Xcode 7.0 Build version 7A220
```

And for firebase and AngularFire, I grab it from firebase CDN:

```
 <!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.2/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is nothing in this example code that would trigger JSON.stringify(). There's also no explanation of how playlists is being constructed, so we wouldn't be able to guess where the circular reference is coming into play.

Comment: There is also no version info here nor enough data to create a repro.

Comment: Ops sorry @Kato ! I edit the post as your last email and I accidentally delete the controller code (and replaced by HTML). My bad! I added all the controller code back and also my version info. Beside above change, I did not modify any other codes from the sidemenu starter. And exactly, I did not trigger any JSON.stringify() in my code and it is when firebaseObject loading into the view and trigger that error!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. It turns out it was being caused in the following scenario:

```
  var userRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users').child(uid);
  profile = $firebaseObject(userRef);
  console.log(profile)
```

Is it possible you are trying to log a firebase data structure that has a cyclic dependency?

Try removing your console.log() lines.

Answer (score 0):

Removing console.log worked for me. I had to do the following to my code (Ionic Google Analytics plugin - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-analytics/)

```
  // Google Analytics (console.log throws errors)
  return GoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-97459358-1")
    .then(() => {
      //console.log('Google analytics is ready now');
      return GoogleAnalytics.enableUncaughtExceptionReporting(true)
    }).then((_success) => {
      //console.log("startTrackerWithId success")
    }).catch((_error) => {
      //console.log("enableUncaughtExceptionReporting", _error)
    })
```